# How to get constant function to keep shape in NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

I have a `NumPy` array `A` with shape `(m,n)` and want to run all the elements through some function `f`. For a non-constant function such as for example `f(x) = x` or `f(x) = x**2` broadcasting works perfectly fine and returns the expected result. For `f(x) = 1`, applying the function to my array `A` however just returns the *scalar* 1.

Is there a way to force broadcasting to keep the shape, i.e. in this case to return an array of 1s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`F(x) = 1` is not a function you need to create a function with `def` or `lambda` and return 1. Then use `np.vectorize` to apply the function on your array.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> f = lambda x: 1
>>> 
>>> f = np.vectorize(f)
>>> 
>>> f(np.arange(10).reshape(2, 5))
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

Comment: We don't really need to take the performance hit of `np.vectorize` for a case as simple as this.

Comment: @user2357112 It's one case, as OP mentioned in question the function can have variant structures.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a job for `np.ones_like`, or `np.full_like` in the general case:

```
def f(x):
    result = np.full_like(x, 1)  # or np.full_like(x, 1, dtype=int) if you don't want to
                                 # inherit the dtype of x
    if result.shape == 0:
        # Return a scalar instead of a 0D array.
        return result[()]
    else:
        return result
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `x.fill(1)`. Make sure to return it properly as `fill` doesn't return a new variable, it modifies `x`